# парсер сайтов на php

Tags: php, парсер

всем привет!

---

в учебных целях хочу написать небольшой парсер. и сейчас мой скрипт парсит ссылки со страницы, пишет их в бд, переходит на следующую страницу, если она есть, дальше рекурсия. загвоздка в том, что он упирается в таймаут ожидания ответа от страницы(?). из вариантов которые приходят в голову - перевести управление запуском парса в консоль, либо на фронт и через аякс посылать запрос а в ответе получать ссылку на следующую страницу и если она есть то повторять запрос. но аякс увеличит время выполнения в разы, хотя и даст возможность сделать некий прогресс-бар. Есть же опытные люди наверняка, как вообще обычно реализуются такие вещи?

Comment: Делали мы подобную вещь на perl + wget. БД не использовали, только файловую систему. Толковый прогресс-бар вы не сможете сделать т.к. заранее не известно количество закачиваемых элементов. Главное в этом моменте - многопоточность. Без неё никуда.

Comment: А можете на пальцах объяснить как организовать многопоточность на рнр? Ниже очереди упоминают, штука крутая, но не уверен, что смогу настроить это все.

Comment: В интернете есть документация на эту тему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в целом в той ситуации, в которой находится каждый новичок, который начинает писать свои программы на PHP: **все скрипты запускаются из браузера**! :)

Ну в целом да, удобно, пока не поймете определенных проблем связанных с timeout, зависанием браузера при выводе большого объема данных и т.д. True разработчики так не делают, потому что познают весь смысл командной строки и ее прелести, поэтому запускают долгие скрипты только от туда и благодаря этому не используются излишне php-fpm.

**Ваша задача при написании программного обеспечения, которое отвечает на запросы пользователей - это максимально быстро отдать ответ, чтобы не засорять очередь запросов!**

Если у вас простой скрипт и нет необходимости в том, чтобы это как-то связывать с клиентской частью, то просто запускайте его из комадной строки с использованием такого понятия, как [аргументы](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.argv.php). В аргумент передавайте адрес, который нужно парсить.

Более сложные варианты реализации, когда требуется например создать форму в которой клиент будет вводить адрес сайта, а вы будете его парсить через какое-то время предполагают использование хранилища для хранения этой информации.

> **Де́мон** (daemon, dæmon, др.-греч. δαίμων божество) — компьютерная
>   программа в системах класса UNIX, запускаемая самой системой и
>   работающая в фоновом режиме без прямого взаимодействия с
>   пользователем.

Для начала, вы можете создавать записи в БД со списком урлов, которые нужно парсить и забирать их скриптом по определенному запросу, который работает в режиме демона. Конечно, вы врятли еще знакомы с понятием демона, поэтому можете начать с создания задачи в [планировщике cron](http://makeasite.ru/cron-setup.html), который будет запускать этот скрипт с определенной периодичностью.

Потом, вы познакомитесь с очередями, [кстати вот тут описан случай который вас интересует](http://www.phphighload.com/2013/08/amqp-rabbitmq.html), и будете использовать действительно мощную и распределенную архитектуру при правильном подходе.

Comment: Раз уж заговорили о демонах, нужно вспомнить какой нибудь супервизор)

Answer (score 0):

Если слишком не заморачиватся, то можно не в браузере запускать, а в консоле `wget`

```
wget -O - -q -t 9999 http://www.example.com/parser/run
```

Параметр `-t 9999` устанавливает время ожидания

Answer (score 0):

1. в массив главную страницу
2. запускаем цикл for или какой другой
3. открываем страницу главную
4. explode('href', страница) или какой у вас там разделитель лучше пойдёт
5. забрали ссылки все и через in_array в основной массив
   Проход не быстрый, но для учебных целей пойдёт, по уму надо валидировать, мультикурл и т.д. тогда будет норм. Про бд, библиотеки можете забыть на большом объёме аукнется, тут всё нормально в оперативке работает, в крайнем случае в файл